# Interpolation model to estimate missing analytics

Tags: arima, missing-data, interpolation

We have about 7 months of partially (30%) missing web analytics, that is apparently missing at random across all segmentations.  We need to estimate the missing data to correctly compare current and future performance, which are doing with an ARIMA on many months of prior data.  However, we have several months of correct data following this period, which is not utilized by the ARIMA model.

Which models might I try that can estimate the missing data using all known, correct data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best to perform multiple imputations of your missing data, rather than simple interpolation. That way you can capture inter-relations of variables beyond time alone, and can estimate the uncertainties introduced by the imputation process. The Amelia package in R was designed to address this issue for time series; its rationale is presented [here](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/pr.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If using R taking a look at these popular packages is a good idea:

AMELIA, mice, VIM - all three contain state-of-the-art imputation methods.
AMELIA is also able to employ multivariate time series features.